# Bootstrap collapsable nav bar not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap and am trying to create one of those collapsable navigation menus that has the three little lines when a small screen is detected. The menu shows up when the screen is big but when it's small the menu disappears.

HTML:

```
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-targert="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      <div><!--end navbar header-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--end myNavbar-->
    </div><!--end container-->
  </nav><!--end nav-->

  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><p style="background-color: yellow">This is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8"><p style="background-color: yellow">This is some text</p></div>
      </div><!--end row-->
  </div><!--end container-->
```

CSS:

Comes from: `<link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/bootstrap.css">` which is the default vendor supplied.

Comment: Please post your css too.

Comment: CSS is the default one used by boostrap. I have not written any.

Comment: 1 data-targert="#myNavbar" ( target spelling is wrong )
2 <div><!--end navbar header--> (div is not closed )
3 <nav class="navbar"> ( use <nav class="navbar navbar-default"> or <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse"> or custom class)

Comment: Thanks. I find it harder to write html and css than programming code since the console does not throw errors on html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Your issue.
1 data-targert="#myNavbar" (target spelling is wrong )
2 <div><!--end navbar header--> (div is not closed )
3 <nav class="navbar"> ( <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse"> or <nav class="navbar navbar-default"> )
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div><!--end navbar header-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--end myNavbar-->
    </div><!--end container-->
  </nav><!--end nav-->

  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><p style="background-color: yellow">This is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some texthis is some text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8"><p style="background-color: yellow">This is some text</p></div>
      </div><!--end row-->
  </div><!--end container-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the navbar style like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
```

OR

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
```

---

If you want a custom styled navbar, then

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar someNavbar">
```

CSS:

```
.someNavbar .navbar-toggle {
    background-color: #FFF; /* change color accordingly */
}
.someNavbar .icon-bar {
    background-color: #000; /* change color accordingly */
}
```

---

Q. What are the above classes?

**`navbar-toggle`** is the main button

**`icon-bar`** are those lines

Also, make sure that your `bootstrap.js` file is loaded **AFTER** the `jQuery.js` file like this:

```
<script src="path/to/jQueryFile"></script>
<script src="path/to/BootstrapFile"></script>
```

And that only one jQuery link is there (Adding more than one jQuery files leads to conflicts in your jQuery dependent scripts).

Comment: The menu appears now but when I click on it it does not drop down to show menu items.

Comment: Can you please refresh the page, click the button again and then check the browser console (F12 in Chrome) and see if any errors are shown.

Comment: Did you add the `<script src="path/to/Bootstrap.js"></script>` too?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was a typo.

Wrong: `data-targert="#myNavbar"`

Correct: `data-target="#myNavbar"`